# python beginner - While loop not breaking when conditions are met

Tags: python, while-loop

I run the program but the loop doesn't stop when the words are equal to 50,000. The output is sometimes over 50,000. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
words = 0
unwanted_comments = 0
comments = 0
keep_going = True

while number_of_comments <= max_comments and keep_going == True:
    num_per_comments = random.randint(1,1050) 
    if number_per_comments <= 1000:
        words = number_per_comments + total
        comments +=1
           if words <= 50000:
              keep_going = True
           else:
              keep_going = False
    else:
        unwanted_comments +=1
```

Comment: You never change the value of `words`, thus it'll always be less than 50k. You should also be careful about the indentation around your if-test.

Comment: Why do you need `keep_going`? Aren't you trying to break out of the loop once you have more than `max_comments`? If so, you don't need `keep_going`.

Comment: In addition to never changing the value of words you also never change the value of number_of_comments

Answer (score -1):

You have to check whether total_words <= 50000 and not words <= 500000, don't you?!

Comment: You should put questions as comments on the original post ;) There's a larger problem here, which is that total_words is never initialized before the while loop, so this code actually crashes. Their actual code must be something different.